# When i press space it says Soldier not defined. Anyone know any fix?

Tags: replit, kaboom

i am using replit
and on replit Kaboom
please tell me if you know any fixes
i have done many many many things and can not fix it
PLEASE HELP ME
code is below

```
import kaboom from "kaboom"

// initialize context
kaboom()

// load assets
loadSprite("Soldier", "sprites/Soldier.png")

// add a character to screen
add([
    // list of components
    sprite("Soldier"),
    pos(80, 40),
    area(),
        body()
])
// add platform
add([
rect(width(), 48),
pos(0, height() - 48),
outline(4),
area(),
solid(),
color(170, 150, 0),
])
onKeyPress("space", () => {
  Soldier.jump()
})

// burp on "b"
onKeyPress("b", burp)
```

I have not been able to find out anything

Answer (score 1):

Assign the value from `add`, otherwise `Soldier` will not be defined:

```
const Soldier = add([
  // ...
])
```

(Also, naming it `Soldier` goes against programming style; though it is not an error as such, `const soldier = add...` and `soldier.jump()` would be better.)